# Comparing int's and Vector2's

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm trying to compare a int to a Vector2 position in an if statement in my code, however I get the error: Operator '<=' can not be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2' and 'int'.

Here is the code snippet:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < Position.Count(); i++) 
            if (Position[i] < positionTracker)
            {
                mSpeed.X = WizardSpeed;
                mDirection.X = MOVE_LEFT;
            }
```

Comment: You are doing the problematic if on a variable called `positionTracker`, but you never show us where you declare it or what you do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error says there is no comparison defined between vector and a numeric value. You options:

- compare one of the components of a vector: `Position[i].X < positionTracker`
- compare absolute value of a vector to numeric value:  `Position[i].Length < positionTracker`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the information you gave so far, you are comparing `Position[i]`, which is of type `Vector2`, and `positionTracker`, which is of type `int`.

How do you compare a vector with an int?

The answer is: You don't. You can compare the absolute of the vector (`Position[i].Length`) to the `int`. Or you can compare one of the coordinates of the vector to the `int`. But you cannot compare a vector with an int. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I got it figured out now. Thank you for that useful information Jan, now I know for future reference.